# Formatting pandas table sorting of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with formatting my tables. This is a simpler version and I will explain it with an example. If I have a table as follows:

```
Col1    Col2

    A   8
    B   2
    C   3
    A   4
    B   5
    C   6
    A   7
    B   1
    C   9
```

I want it to be arranged where highest value of col2 comes first. In this case it is 9 from account C. Therefore all account C values follow, arranged in Col2 order. Next, highest value is shown by account A, so all account A values follow, again arranged in Col2 values order.
The final table should look something like this:

```
Col1    Col2
C   9
C   6
C   3
A   8
A   7
A   4
B   5
B   2
B   1
```

What would be the best way to do this. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need create a help key for `sort_values` by `groupby` `transform`

```
df['helperkey']=df.groupby('Col1').Col2.transform('max')
df.sort_values(['helperkey','Col2'],ascending=[False,False]).drop('helperkey',1)
Out[102]: 
  Col1  Col2
8    C     9
5    C     6
2    C     3
0    A     8
6    A     7
3    A     4
4    B     5
1    B     2
7    B     1
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but you could figure out the order, set column `Col1` to be an ordered categorical, and sort by `Col1` and `Col2`, in ascending and descending order respectively:

```
order = df.groupby('Col1').max().sort_values('Col2', ascending=False).index

df['Col1'] = pd.Categorical(df['Col1'], categories=order, ordered=True)

df.sort_values(['Col1', 'Col2'], ascending=[True,False])

  Col1  Col2
8    C     9
5    C     6
2    C     3
0    A     8
6    A     7
3    A     4
4    B     5
1    B     2
7    B     1
```